# How to show all the value of all customers that have even one of filtered values in power bi

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have the table of customers with different statuses in different months
[image: Customer Data].
I have added Status value In Power BI Slicer Visual to filter the Matrix Data. And when, selecting for example A, it only shows customers who has A status in certain period.

Filtered Customer Data
[image: Filtered Customer Data].

(6 an 8 are missing because they don't have status A in any period). The Problem is that I want to see all the statuses of the customers who even once had status A. is it possible somehow in Power BI ?

Result I want to See
[image: Result I want to See]

Answer (score 1):

Good news: there is a pretty easy fix for this.

Create a new table using DAX.

```
FilterableStatuses = 

SUMMARIZE(
    DemoData,
    DemoData[CustomerID],
    DemoData[Status]
)
```

Create a relationship in your model between CustomerID on this new table and CustomerID on the table from your visual.  It will be Many to Many and I prefer to not leave the filter direction as 'both' -- make it so FilterableStatus filters your original table.

Create a slicer using the status from FilterableStatuses rather than the original table, and that should give you the behavior that you're after.  In essence, rather than filter the visual by [Status], you are filtering the list of CustomerIDs by status, and then letting the new relationship filter your visual to CustomerIDs

Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: It's what I wanted, thank you a lot.